# VBA dynamic feed multiple files into current one but error of "Run-rime error 7 out of memory" occurs

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, dynamic, range

```
Sub CopyFromWorkbook(frombook As String, fromsheet As Variant, fromrange As Variant, tosheet As Variant, torange As Variant, wb As String, clearwhat As Variant)

Dim copyto, copyfrom As Workbook
Dim ref As Range

Set copyto = ThisWorkbook
If Not (IsWorkbookOpen(wb)) Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:=frombook
Else
Workbooks(wb).Activate
End If

Set copyfrom = ActiveWorkbook
Set ref = copyfrom.Worksheets(fromsheet).Range(fromrange)

copyto.Activate
copyto.Worksheets(tosheet).Range(clearwhat).ClearContents
copyto.Worksheets(tosheet).Range(torange).Resize(ref.Rows.count, ref.Columns.count).Value = ref.Value
copyto.Worksheets(tosheet).Calculate

End Sub
```

I use below code to run dynamic feed and it succeeds. But for a different set of files, it failed. I already adjust for data range.

the error show

[image]

Comment: Why do you define nearly everything as a variant? Even your `copyto` is an indirect variant since you need to specify per variable which type it is, i.e. `Dim copyto As Workbook, copyfrom As Workbook`. If `frombook` is the filename from `wb`, then just use `Set copyfrom = Workbooks.Open(frombook)`, then you don't need that entire If-else-clause nor any need for the activate. About the memory issue, how big is your `ref`?

Comment: Saving `copyto` after each calculate should help to reduce memory usage. If the `ref` is too big, cutting it up in smaller chunks (like looping through the columns) could help as well.